# Confusing and Logout button not working on top right corner

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Today I was using Stack Overflow Careers when I noticed a confusing flow in your site. I believe it should be addressed or if it is due to some logic please explain it to me. I am including the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The link in the top bar takes you to the logout page. It's not a logout button itself. The top bar navigation doesn't change as you move around the site. (For example, the "messages" link goes to the same place even when you're already on the Messages page.)

So, yes, you need to click the orange button on the logout page to confirm that you do intend to log out.